# Можно ли создать двух разных телеграм ботов и разместив их на хостинге, сделать так, чтобы один бот подключался к базе данных второго бота?

Tags: python, aiogram, хостинг

Хочу написать два разных бота на aiogram, и, разместив их на хостинге, сделать так, чтобы второй бот в своей работе подключался к базе данных второго бота. Всем спасибо заранее